# Get folders with PHP glob - unlimited levels deep

Tags: php, foreach, directory, glob

I have this working function that finds folders and creates an array.

```
function dua_get_files($path)
{
    foreach (glob($path . "/*", GLOB_ONLYDIR) as $filename)
    {
        $dir_paths[] = $filename;   
    }
    return $dir_paths;
}
```

This function can only find the directories on the current location. I want to find the directory paths in the child folders and their children and so on.

The array should still be a flat list of directory paths.

**An example of how the output array should look like**

```
$dir_path[0] = 'path/folder1';
$dir_path[1] = 'path/folder1/child_folder1';
$dir_path[2] = 'path/folder1/child_folder2';
$dir_path[3] = 'path/folder2';
$dir_path[4] = 'path/folder2/child_folder1';
$dir_path[5] = 'path/folder2/child_folder2';
$dir_path[6] = 'path/folder2/child_folder3';
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you want to recursively work on directories, you should take a look at the [**`RecursiveDirectoryIterator`**](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php).

```
$path = realpath('/etc');

$objects = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
foreach($objects as $name => $object){
    echo "$name\n";
}
```

Comment: Yes, that worked. I edited and added the code for others to see in your answer.

Comment: why RecursiveDirectoryIterator class ? view my answer

Comment: @Davood because, using that iterator, there is no need to do the recursion yourself ;-) ;; @Jens your edit is pending approval, and needs one more "approve vote" to be displayed ; if it's not approved soon, I'll edit myself, to add what you posted ; thanks !

Comment: Probably a server disable this class or not founded !

Comment: Chances of having this class disabled or it not defined are pretty low : it's a standard class provided by PHP >= 5.1 ; and there is pretty much no security reason to disable it.

Comment: I prefer to be can't use from this class, because when possible not use this class, it no have necessary

Comment: Not sure I really understand what you mean ; but if PHP provides such classes, why just not use them ?

Comment: Heu... if your server doesn't have PHP >= 5.1.2 *(which is more than years old !)*, you have a problem ^^ PHP 5.2 *(which is older than 5.1, especially for 5.2.17)* itself has reached its end of life... If you consider you must write code that has to be compatible with PHP < 5.1, well, good luck ! *(and I wouldn't like to be at your place, actually)*

Answer (score 10):

Very strange - everybody advice recursion, but better just cycle:

```
$dir ='/dir';
while($dirs = glob($dir . '/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR)) {
  $dir .= '/*';
  if(!$result) {
     $result = $dirs;
   } else {
      $result = array_merge($result, $dirs);
   }
}
```

Comment: Nice! But, of course, there's absolutely nothing "very strange" about it: using a recursive procedure to iterate a recursive structure is probably the most obvious thing to do.

Answer (score 6):

Try this instead:

```
function dua_get_files($path)
{
    $data = array();
    $files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

    foreach ($files as $file)
    {
        if (is_dir($file) === true)
        {
            $data[] = strval($file);
        }
    }

    return $data;
}
```

Comment: @DennisMeissner: neither is the accepted answer but  apparently it does the job. Using glob for this task is just nonsense.

Answer (score 4):

Use this function :

```
function dua_get_files($path)
{
    $dir_paths = array();
    foreach (glob($path . "/*", GLOB_ONLYDIR) as $filename)
    {
        $dir_paths[] = $filename;
        $a = glob("$filename/*", GLOB_ONLYDIR);
        if( is_array( $a ) )
        {
            $b = dua_get_files( "$filename/*" );
            foreach( $b as $c )
            {
                $dir_paths[] = $c;
            }
        }
    }
    return $dir_paths;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use php GLOB function, but you must create a recursive function to scan directories at infinite level depth. Then store results in a global variable.

```
function dua_get_files($path) {
    global $dir_paths; //global variable where to store the result
    foreach ($path as $dir) { //loop the input
        $dir_paths[] = $dir; //can use also "basename($dir)" or "realpath($dir)"
        $subdir =  glob($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '*', GLOB_ONLYDIR); //use DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR to be OS independent
        if (!empty($subdir)) { //if subdir is not empty make function recursive
            dua_get_files($subdir); //execute the function again with current subdir
        }
    }
}

//usage:
$path = array('galleries'); //suport absolute or relative path. support one or multiple path
dua_get_files($path);
print('<pre>'.print_r($dir_paths,true).'</pre>'); //debug
```

Answer (score 0):

For **PHP**, if you are on a linux/unix, you can also use backticks (shell execution) with the unix `find` command.  Directory searching on the filesystem can take a long time and hit a loop -- the system `find` command is already built for speed and to handle filesystem loops.  In other words, the system exec call is likely to cost far less cpu-time than using PHP itself to search the filesystem tree.

```
$dirs = `find $path -type d`;
```

Remember to sanitize the $path input, so other users don't pass in security compromising path names (like from the url or something).

To put it into an array

```
$dirs = preg_split("/\s*\n+\s*/",`find $path -type d`,-1,PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

Comment: This answer is cross-version, recursion, and permission tolerant (provided the server doesn't have apache/php-fpm running as root).  This will even run and produce correct results on PHP 3!  You can pre-order the find-results by passing in the right arguments to find in the first place.  The unix find is objectively faster than directory recursing in php.