# How to echo all the folder names in a particular folder using php?

Tags: php

I want to print the folder names in a particular folder. For example Folder 1,2,3 are in a folder named 'New' I want to print the folder names 1 2 3 using php. Is it possible ? is there any function in php to do that ? any kind of solutions or ideas are very much appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/608450/using-scandir-to-find-folders-in-a-directory-php

Comment: @mgraph I have tried the above solution, but it did't worked as you can see there is no accepted answer..!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get folders with PHP glob - unlimited levels deep](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5769514/get-folders-with-php-glob-unlimited-levels-deep)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$dir = "/etc/php5/";

// Open a known directory, and proceed to read its contents
if (is_dir($dir)) {
    if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
        while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
            echo "filename: $file : filetype: " . filetype($dir . $file) . "\n";
        }
        closedir($dh);
    }
}
?>
```

credit to [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.opendir.php)

Extending this logic,

```
<?php
$dir = "/etc/php5/";

// Open a known directory, and proceed to read its contents
if (is_dir($dir)) {
    if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
        while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
            if(filetype($dir . $file) == 'dir') {
                echo "filename: $file : filetype: " . filetype($dir . $file) . "\n";
            }
        }
        closedir($dh);
    }
}
?>
```

should echo all directories

The output on my local server is:

```
filename: . : filetype: dir
filename: .. : filetype: dir
filename: apache : filetype: dir
filename: etc : filetype: dir
filename: pranav : filetype: dir
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is some example code from php.net on the [readdir()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php) function:

```
<?php
if ($handle = opendir('.')) {
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {
            echo "$entry\n";
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
?>
```

If you modify this code to check $entry with the [is_dir()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php) function, you can easily find your directories.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php       

    // declare the folder    
    $ourDir = "/home/public_html/folderName";

    // prepare to read directory contents    
    $ourDirList = @opendir($ourDir);

    // loop through the items    
    while ($ourItem = readdir($ourDirList))    
    {        
       // check if it is a directory    
       if (is_dir($ourItem))    
       {    
          echo "directory: $ourItem <br />";    
       }

       // check to see if it is a file    
       if (is_file($ourItem))    
       {    
          echo "file: $ourItem <br />";    
       }    
    }

closedir($ourDirList);

?>
```

This is to echo both folders and files in a Directory.

Answer (score 1):

glob function can be used to fetch directories too.

```
<?php
  $folders = glob('/',GLOB_ONLYDIR);
  print_r($folders);
?>
```