# How to use RecursiveIteratorIterator to generate a multi-level HTML menu?

Tags: php, html, recursion, iterator, spl

I'm having trouble getting my head around `RecrusiveIteratorIterator` and relatives to iterate over an multi-dimensional array of pages to build a multi-level menu in PHP.

Normally I just create a function that loops over a level, and calls itself to loop over any children. But I'm wanting to utilise the iterator interfaces in PHP to make my code better.

My array looks like this:

```
$pages = array(
    new Page(1, 'Home'),
    new Page(2, 'Pages', array(
        new Page(3, 'About'),
        new Page(4, 'Contact')
    )),
    new Page(5, 'Categories', array(
        new Page(6, 'Clothing'),
        new Page(7, 'DVDs')
    ))
);
```

The arguments in my `Page` constructor are simply the page ID and page name.

How can I use PHP's iterators to build a menu that looks like this?

```
<ul>
  <li>Home</li>
  <li>Pages
    <ul>
      <li>About</li>
      <li>Contact</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Categories
    <ul>
      <li>Clothing</li>
      <li>DVDs</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I convert a series of parent-child relationships into a hierarchical tree?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2915748/how-can-i-convert-a-series-of-parent-child-relationships-into-a-hierarchical-tre), for your particular problem, see this answer in there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2915748/how-can-i-convert-a-series-of-parent-child-relationships-into-a-hierarchical-tre/8285070#8285070

Comment: Also see hgere: [RecursiveIteratorIterator and RecursiveDirectoryIterator to nested html lists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10779546/recursiveiteratoriterator-and-recursivedirectoryiterator-to-nested-html-lists)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is normally a three step procedure:

1. You implement a concrete [`RecursiveIterator`](http://php.net/RecursiveIterator) that offers recursion iteration for your tree structure. It looks like that [`RecursiveArrayIterator`](http://php.net/RecursiveArrayIterator) is suiting your needs here.
2. You iterate over it with a [`RecursiveIteratorIterator`](http://php.net/RecursiveIteratorIterator) that is able to turn the recusion into your output (compare with  [`RecursiveTreeIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivetreeiterator.php)).
3. You do the output by iterating with `foreach` over your more concrete `RecursiveIteratorIterator`.

Code Example:

```
   // consume implementation of step 1
   $it = new PagesRecursiveIterator($pages);

   // consume implementation of step 2
   $list = new RecursiveUlLiIterator($it);

   // perform iteration given in step 3
   foreach($list as $page) {
       echo $page->getName();
   }
```