# PHP function error in generating directory tree as a nested html list

Tags: php, html

I have a directory that has a depth of at least 3 or 4 levels. I'm trying to recurse through the directory tree as deep and generate a HTML unordered nested list.

The code I'm using creates a nested HTML list but it is not in the correct directory depth order. This is what it is currently producing which is not correct.

[image: Current wrong output]

This is what I am trying to achieve

[image: this output]

My current code is below. Which part do I need to modify to make this work?

```
<?php
function read_dir_tree($parent_dir, $depth = 0){
    $str_result = "";

    $str_result .= "<li>". dirname($parent_dir) ."</li>";
    $str_result .= "<ul>";
    if ($handle = opendir($parent_dir)) 
    {
        while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle)))
        {
            if(in_array($file, array('.', '..'))) continue;
            if( is_dir($parent_dir . "/" . $file) ){
                $str_result .= "<li>" . read_dir_tree($parent_dir . "/" . $file, $depth++) . "</li>";
            }
            $str_result .= "<li>{$file}</li>";
        }
        closedir($handle);
    }
    $str_result .= "</ul>";


    return $str_result;
}

function read_dir($tp){
$link = ($tp);
echo "<ul>".read_dir_tree($link)."</ul>";
}
?>
```

I call this PHP from HTML using:

```
<?php
read_dir("media");
?>
```

Comment: What you want is not valid HTML: `<li>` elements are not allowed to have a `<li>` element as parent. If you do that, the first of the two is considered closed, and so they are siblings. The `</li>` tag of the parent is then wrongly positioned.

Comment: @trincot is right. You can see a nested list example on [w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_lists_nested)

Answer (score -1):

max514, this has already been answered here with a full working example.

[RecursiveIteratorIterator and RecursiveDirectoryIterator to nested html lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10779546/recursiveiteratoriterator-and-recursivedirectoryiterator-to-nested-html-lists)

Comment: This should have been a comment. Once you have the required reputation you can vote to close a question as duplicate.

Comment: trincot, I understand. I don't have the reputation yet to comment or suggest duplicate, so I wrote it as an answer.

Comment: Still, that is not a valid reason to post it as an answer. There is a reason why reputation requirements exist. To work around them in this way is not their purpose.

Comment: trincot, ok so for people looking for help, and it is already answered in another stack, I am suppose to just move along and not help and ignore the fact they need help because I lack reputation. Sounds reasonable. (sigh)

Comment: Sorry brother i'm afraid DomDocument method will not work for this. I'll append div tags and href link to every ul for bootstrap sorry i didnt mentioned that in the question   pls remove marked as duplicate.

Comment: max514, you should be able to use that with your HTML concepts you are speaking of.