# Browse sub folders of a folder [ Different name for the sub folders ]

Tags: php, arrays, image, gallery, directory

This how the folders looks:

```
Website/ Index-Profil/ Profil-Images/ Images/ $_SESSION['username']/ PublicImg NUM 1


Website/ Index_Public_Images/ Public-Images/ Images
```

And I wish that the folder 
`Public-Images/Images` 
contains all the images which are located in the sub folders of 
`Profil-images/Images/$Session['username']/`

OR

at least show the images which are located in the sub folders and have the name `Publicxxxxxx`.

Answer (score 0):

You wil need To make a function that scans your dir like scandir() and loop trough all the folders found by that function and rescan each folder again with scandir()

Comment: :D can you explain more ? :p

Answer (score 0):

I don't know it the following function is completely correct, because i just wrote it while i'm studying. But the idea is good, the function you are looking for, will be something like this:

```
$glob_dir_list = array();
function ScanDirTree($dir){
$maindir = scandir($dir);
foreach($maindir as $subdir){
if(is_dir($subdir)){
$ndir = ScanDirTree($subdir);
array_push($glob_dir_list,$ndir);
}
}
}
```

the glob_dir_list array will hold all the folders in your folder and it's subfolders. if you want me to write you a really good function, please tell me.
ALSO THIS IS A GOOD THREAD [Recursive directory scanning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10748387/php-script-to-traverse-directory-file-tree-and-output-tree-as-nested-uls)

Comment: :/ I still can't make it can anyone please help me for this one ! it's a little bit hard for me :D

Comment: Well I can browse the folders and extract the name of images which begin with PUBLIC like this, but I don't know if the way if correct or not 
<?php
 foreach (glob("./../Index_Profil/Profil_Images/Thumbnails/*/Public*") as $file) 
  {
   if($file == '.' || $file == '..') continue;
   print $file . '<br>';
  }
?>
the code works great and I can show images